# typeahead 0.11.1 remote does not showing returned data

Tags: asp.net-mvc, typeahead.js

I was implementing the latest version of typeahead with my MVC app. The situation is, i got the json results, which is fine and validated.

In the return section of typeahead, i put an alert and I can see that all the returned results are there. But when it comes to display, nothing is being shown. No error message in console as well. XHR is completely fine.

Frankly, I have no idea why is this happening? Could you please gimme any ideas..Thanks in advance

Typeahead version used: 0.11.1

the following is my code..

```
<div class="tt-container">
    <input  id="customer" name="customer" type="text" value="" class="form-control" required />
</div>
```

Typeahead Declaration

```
var customers = new Bloodhound({
                datumTokenizer: function (d) { return Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace(d.value); },
                queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
                remote: {
                    url: '/api/customer?query=%QUERY',
                    wildcard: '%QUERY',
                    filter: function(customers) {
                        //debugger;
                        return $.map(customers,function(user) {
                            //debugger;
                            alert(user.customerName);
                            return {
                                value: user.customerName
                            };
                        });
                    }
                },
                ajax: {
                    type: "GET",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    beforeSend: function(jqXhr, settings) {
                        var authHeaders;
                        // pull apart jqXHR, set authHeaders to what it should be
                        //debugger;
                        jqXhr.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
                    }
                }
            });

            customers.initialize();

            $('#customer').typeahead({
                    minLength: 3,
                    highlight: true
                },
                {
                    name: 'customers',
                    displayKey: 'value',
                    source: customers.ttAdapter()
                });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dig on this issue and found that typeahead has few unresolved issues and this is one of them. So I decided to go with jquery autocomplete, which has all the features of typeahead.

Comment: Actually, typeahead was now only maintained by community on the different repository at https://github.com/corejavascript/typeahead.js
If you haven't really implemented using jQuery Autocomplete you might switch to this version to see. It works for the remote source on my use case.

Comment: I see...yes you are right...this wasn't the source from which I downloaded typeahead....but anyway jquery autocomplete is good as well and serves the same as per my need

Comment: I understand that. So please mark the current answer as resolved. :D